# checking that a table contains a group of records

Tags: postgresql

I have a table as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE trip_locations(
    trip_id     int NOT NULL,
    city_id     bigint,
    country_id  smallint,
    
    FOREIGN KEY (trip_id) references trips (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (city_id) references cities (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (country_id) references countries (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Currently, row contains either city_id, or country_id.

However, that can change, i.e - a row might include both the city_id and the corresponding country_id.
How can I make sure to support both cases :

- in the query below to check city_id irrespective of their country_id value?
- the opposite: include city_id only if the country_id matches also

I need to make sure that certain combinations exist here for a given trip.

The query I had in mind is like this :

```
WITH must_exist (city_id, country_id) AS (VALUES (4010, NULL), (NULL, 193))
SELECT COUNT(*) = COUNT(must_exist.*) AS result
FROM must_exist
JOIN trip_locations
ON   must_exist.city_id::bigint = trip_locations.city_id
OR   must_exist.country_id::smallint = trip_locations.country_id
WHERE trip_locations.trip_id = 123
```

But it's not working correctly, it results in TRUE when it shouldn't.

Comment: 1) You will need to explain further what you mean by exist? As `null` means lack of/unknown value so `(1, null)` does not have a `country_id`. 2) You need to add to your question the query you are using and example of how it is not working.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks, I've edited the post, I hope it's clearer now

Comment: 1) *...include city_id only if the country_id matches also* matches any `country_id` or the correct one for the `city_id`? 2) *But it's not working correctly, it results in TRUE when it shouldn't.* What is the shouldn't?

Comment: 1. for now at least any one, but would be helpful to learn how to manage both cases.
2. I think it doesn't work because "COUNT(must_exist.*)" always returns the same number as COUNT(*).  If I replace it with a hardcoded number, it seems to work. (but don't know how efficient that solution is with COUNT)